# Change date format to ISO 8601 using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, format

I have 2 input fields that when a user inputs the date in say mm-dd-yyyy format, i would like to have it automatically change to yyyy-mm-dd (ISO 8601 Date Format)

the input fields are very simple:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="purchase_date">Purchase Date <font size="-3">(Year-MM-DD) format</font></label>
        <input type="text" name="purchase_date" class="form-control"  placeholder="Purchase Date">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="warranty_end_date">Warranty End Date <font size="-3">(Year-MM-DD) format</font></label>
        <input type="text" name="warranty_end_date" class="form-control"  placeholder="Warranty End Date">
</div>
```

is there a way to do this without using datepicker?  I dont want to add any extra styling sheets or any extra js..

Comment: Why not enforce the input (perhaps with dropdowns) in the first place rather than guess what has been entered. Who is to say that they didn't enter `dd-mm-yyyy` and how would you know with something like `10-12-2014`? or use `mmm` and `dd` and `yyyy`, then you would know what is what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [this Pen](http://codepen.io/alcidesqueiroz/pen/iwqah) I've created. I'm accepting both mm/dd/yyyy and mm-dd-yyyy formats and doing the conversion on the blur of each input.

Comment: So i copied everything exactly and added the classes as well.  but its still not converting, its not even doing anything. but it is working on codepen...

Comment: does it matter that it is loaded in a modal?

Comment: Yeap, in your case, the script should run after the modal DOM is fully rendered.

Comment: yea, i moved the scripts to the top page(right after all the other scripts are loaded) and it worked, I added an alert to tell me when it was there so I knew where to put it! haha  Thanks for your help!